I can't figure out how to get p256dh key and auth from PushSubscription
How do I get these values, where are they taken/generated from?
I understand how to get a token from fcm, I have a public server key, but I still don’t understand how p256dh and auth keys are generated. I'm doing traffic sniffing to understand where the values ​​come from.I figured out all the meanings except these two.

Those are simply properties of the PushSubscription object that you get by calling PushManager.subscribe(). Here's a more detailed explanation of the PushSubscription object.

I understand that the browser generates these parameters, but I can’t understand what input parameters are needed
